# Cannot cd to a folder with spaces in the the folder path

Tags: powershell

I am trying to `cd` to the `Program Files` directory, but I'm getting an error. Here is the screen shot.

[image: PowerShell Error Message]

Here's the command I'm running and the error message:

> PS C:\> cd C:\Program Files
>
> Set-Location : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Files'.
>   At line:1 char:3
>   + cd  <<<< C:\Program Files

Comment: there's whitespace, escape it.

Comment: `cd "C:\Program Files"`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Type `cd c:\` . Now press the tab key (this is auto-complete, which will save you a lot of typing) repeatedly until it shows you a directory with spaces in the name. Notice how it delimits the path with apostrophes `'`. Use the same character when you're typing.

Edit: Make sure to use an apostrophe, not a backtick.

Comment: @downvoter What was wrong with this answer? How could I improve it?

Answer (score 44):

You need to surround the path in double quotes if there is a space in the path!

```
cd "C:\Program Files"
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the ProgramFiles environment variable

```
cd $env:ProgramFiles
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
C:\>cd "Program Files"
```

This will work.

Answer (score 1):

**METHOD1**: With Quotes

> `cd "C:/Prgram Files (x86)"`
>
> `cd 'C:/Program Files (x86)'`

**Method2**: Without using Quotes

> `cd Program\ Files \(x86\)`

Similarly it will go for Program Files.

Answer (score -2):

Try then 8.3 filename version:

```
cd C:\Progra~1
```

Also try:

```
cd C:\Program*
```

Answer (score -3):

You should try with

```
cd C:\Program\ Files
```

Comment: No, he shouldn't. The backslash is a path separator here, not an escape character. He must either quote the path (as has already suggested) or escape spaces with backticks: `cd C:\Program\` Files`

Comment: Even the suggested edit is wrong. Declined.